# Formatting problems with CellFormatting DataGridView Event

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell-formatting

Here's the problem I'm experiencing: I have a `DataGridView` (let's call it A) where I list many records that come from a `SqlDataReader`. This `DataGridView` is populated on the `SelectionChanged` event of *another* grid. I need to paint the rows **red** if the date from the forth column in grid A is **greater than** today (newer), else it paints the row as **blue**.

Here's the code that I implemented in the `CellFormatting` event to do so:

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(dgvCREListaParcelas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value) > DateTime.Now)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        }
```

I don't know why, but whenever I click any row in the grid, or scroll down and up, the lines' colors change. Unfortunately, I'm not able to post an image, as I don't have enough points to do so!

Would anyone be able to help with this problem?

Comment: I've managed to fix this, by changing the following line in the CellFormating Event:
if (Convert.ToDateTime(dgvCREListaParcelas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value) < DateTime.Now)

To:

if (Convert.ToDateTime(dgvCREListaParcelas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value) < DateTime.Now)

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this, by changing the following line in the CellFormating Event:
if (Convert.ToDateTime(dgvCREListaParcelas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value) < DateTime.Now)

To:

if (Convert.ToDateTime(dgvCREListaParcelas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value) < DateTime.Now)

Thanks for the attention!